# Obfuscated Django URL for model objects

Tags: django, obfuscation, django-urls

I have a Django model that looks something like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name='people')
    approved = models.BooleanField()
    objects = PersonManager()

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return('deal_details', (), {
            'person_slug': slugify(self.name),
        })
```

As you could see, I already have an absolute URL for the object. However, I want to create a difficult-to-guess URL to keep track of the approval process of the object. Anyone done something similar and/or have any suggestions on how I should proceed?

My first thought was creating a model field like `obfuscated_key` that is generated randomly via the [`save` function of the model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects). Then the URL would look something like `/people/status/<id>/<obfuscated_key>/`. But perhaps there's a better way to go about this?

Comment: Either you care about security in this case and should use real logins, or you don't and can skip the obfuscation step. Either way is superior to security through obscurity. If you really want to pretend it's useful, you can use a hash of the thing you're trying to hide.

Comment: @Nathon: Bypassing the attitude---"want to pretend it's useful" sounds augmentative and pretencious to me---I believe you make a great point. Thank you sincerely. Much obliged. This type of obfuscation is usually used for short lifespan pages such as password resets. Perhaps I should rethink if it fits my purpose. Appreciate your input.

Comment: @Nathon: What is the difference between some random hash and login+password ? If someone guesses or intercepts any of them, you're done anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good way to do this would be to hash the object's ID with the installation's secret key (from settings.py). This is what the password reset email form does - there's some useful code in `django.contrib.auth.tokens` - and, in the very latest SVN versions, `django.contrib.auth.crypto`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like a URL shortener (read: obfuscating) might work.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1323/

Answer (score 0):

I've used UUIDField to do something similar.

In the model:

```
uuid = UUIDField(auto=True)
```

then in the view check the id and uuid:

```
item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=id, uuid__exact=uuid)
```

The UUIDField is from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/335/